# issue with length macro

Tags: c, macros

I have a simple macro:

```
#define LENGTH(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))
```

and for whatever reason, it seems to work fine when setting something like:

```
int length = LENGTH(arr)
```

but not to compare with in a loop

```
while(i < LENGTH(arr))
```

Comment: All of that should work fine; please show some more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the same `arr`, the macro will either work or it won't.

The likely problem is that the `arr` in the loop is a *pointer* rather than an *array*. The macro does not work with pointers, it only works with arrays.

Comment: My answer is basically the same as this, but I explain why...

Comment: @NPE I should have provided that detail, the while loop is in fact in a function with arr passed in. Is there a better way to calculate length of the array when treated as a pointer? Also I've been under the impression that arrays and pointers are generally interchangeable..

Comment: @BrianMaher: Have a read of http://c-faq.com/aryptr/

Comment: @BrianMaher: You'll have to explicitly pass the length of the array into the function. When the array decays into a pointer, the size information is lost.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that arrays *decays to pointer* when passed around. So if you pass an array to a function, it's not longer an array but a pointer inside the function. A pointer which have only have information about the type, but not the size of the array.

Comment: Check out my comment to NPE's answer. Your answer is correct. I just need an alternate method of calculating length then. Is there a way that would work for both pointers and arrays?

Comment: @BrianMaher No there is no way of getting the length of the memory a pointer points to. You have to pass it along as an argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks, I got there now. I was just hoping there was a way to avoid doing that.

Answer (score -2):

`sizeof(arr)` is not the same as what a more high level language gives you when you do `arr.Count()` or `arr.Length`.

This gives you the storage space of the `arr` variable. This *does not* mean the length of the array.

If you have `char *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * 100);` and you do `sizeof(arr)` you will usually (depending on your system) get 4. If you do `sizeof(*arr)` or `sizeof(arr[0])`, which is the same thing, you have `sizeof(char)` which is 1, so the macro gives you 4/1 = 4 : wrong. It works with `char arr[100]` because `sizeof(arr)` gives you 100 as the array does not decay to a pointer type for `sizeof`.

Comment: Well, no, but that's why the division is used, of course. This is a good answer, but it's worded to make it sound as if the OP's code is *always* wrong, which is really isn't.

Comment: I'm not saying the code will _never_ work, I'm saying _be careful_ because `sizeof(arr)` does not do what you think it does. OP's asking why this fails, this is my answer. Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: thats why he is using a macro to calculate the number of elements inside the array.

Comment: Why the downvote now? My answer is perfectly right I think, so if you think I'm wrong tell me.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel the macro won't do anything more than `sizeof` __that's the point__.

Comment: it will, if `arr` is an array, it will return the number of elements of that array. If is a pointer, it will not, but the macro is correct.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel Have you read my answer? I never said the macro is incorrect. I said thinking `sizeof(arr)` gives you the full total size of the array's elements is _wrong_

Comment: @JonatanGoebel having a macro to calculate what must be, in `C`, a fixed size, processed before runtime, is really useless, don't you think? A macro is there for readability, yeah sure, so why no just declare `#define LENGTH 100` and use `char arr[LENGTH]; and while (i < LENGTH)` and stop running in circles ?

Comment: @JonatanGoebel If you are in a need for such calculation I guess you _don't know_ the size of the array to start with, so it's more than likely to _not_ be a fixed size array but a pointer to a malloc'd space -> The macro is useless.

Comment: In response to your original post. I get what you're saying, but that's why I divided by sizeof(arr[0]) (in this case equivalent to saying sizeof(int)) in order to get the number of elements rather than bytes.

Comment: Dividing won't do anything good if you do not divide the correct number.